# How to use typescript definition files outside of ./node_modules/@types

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I'd like to improve a package installed at `node_modules/@types`, but I don't want to edit it there since `node_modules` can get deleted and/or updated. When I move a folder out of `node_modules/@types`, intellisense in VSCode no longer works. I have edited the files, paths, include, and `typeRoots` fields in `tsconfig` to match the new location without luck. Does anyone know how to setup VSCode and/or `tsconfig` to get intellisense to work when a folder is moved out of `node_modules/@types`?

Comment: The reason why your intelligence doesn't work when you move your file out the folder is that you have installed the respective definition file within that folder.

Please install the d.ts file in global path of TS.

Hope this helps you. If not let me know i'll help further.

Answer (score -1):

Module augmentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Scroll to the bottom.